# How do spectral neural networks for learning on graphs work?

Tags: neural-networks, convolution, spectral-analysis, graph-neural-network

I've been reading this paper ["Spectral Networks and Locally Connected Networks on Graphs"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6203v2.pdf) but for the full understanding of this paper it requires the reader to be knowledgeable about harmonic analysis which I'm not. So how would you explain the convolution-like operation that is supposed to generalize conventional convolution to ones on graph structures?